# Cauchy Schwarz inequality on $V \wedge V $

Tags: inequality, euclidean-geometry, geometric-inequalities

the Cauchy Schwarz inequality says for example 
$$ (a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2)(b_1^2+b_2^2+b_3^2)
\geq (a_1 b_1+ a_2 b_2+a_3 b_3)^2$$
and with clever choices of $a$ and $b$ we can solve many problems.  It can be read as saying $\cos \theta \leq 1$. It can be interpreted as quantifying the pigeonhole principle.  Also it's related to the distance from a point to a line (leading to a proof). Half of real analysis is clever usages of this inequality.

Cauchy Schwartz works because it's related to Pythagoras theorem, and it extends to $n$ variables and to metric spaces. So here is my question.  Let $V=\mathbb{R}^n$ with the dot product.  Then $V \wedge V$ is also an inner product space with an induced inner product. How do I write the Cauchy Schwartz inequality there.

for Pythagoras theorem I have 
$$ |v \wedge w |^2= \sum (v_i w_j   - w_i  v_j)^2$$
which says the area squares of a parallelogram in $n$ space is the sum of the area squares of each projection into pairs of coordinate axes.

what is the analogue of Cauchy Schwartz?

Comment: How is this an inner product?

Comment: @JackyChong it is a norm, you can extract the inner product using the parallelogram:  $$ \langle a, b \rangle =  \frac{1}{4}\big(|| a + b ||^2 - ||a - b||^2\big)  $$

Comment: But $|v\wedge v|^2 = 0$.

Comment: @JackyChong there are two inner products.  There is $(V , \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_1)$ with basis $\{ e_1, \dots, e_n\}$ and there is an inner product on the wedge space $ (V \wedge V, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_2)$ with $e_i \wedge e_j , e_k\wedge e_l$ perpendicular unless $i = k$ and $j = l$ or unless $i = l$ and $j = k$.  Cauchy Schwartz inequality could refer to:
$$ \langle v, w \rangle_1 \leq ||v||_1 \; ||w||_1 $$
or the same with respect the second norm. Can you picture this?
$$ \langle v_1 \wedge v_2, w_1 \wedge w_2 \rangle_2 \leq ||v_1 \wedge v_2||_1 \; ||w_1 \wedge w_2||_2 $$

Comment: Okay. My mistake. I completely understand. So what's your question since you already understand $\langle v_1\wedge v_2, w_1\wedge w_2\rangle \leq \| v_1\wedge v_2\|_2 \|w_1\wedge w_2\|_2$?